# passing const pointer parameter to function with boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, boost, parameters

I have a function as follows

```
 void test(const int * x, int d){
     for(int i=0; i<d ; i++)
         cout<< x[i] << endl;
 }
```

When I try to run it with a boost::thread

```
int n=10;
int * x1=new int[n];
boost::thread *new_thread = new boost::thread(& test,x1,n);
```

I get the following compilation error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int*&, uint16_t&)’
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:216: note: candidates are: boost::thread::thread(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::thread>)
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:155: note:                 boost::thread::thread()
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:123: note:                 boost::thread::thread(boost::detail::thread_data_ptr)
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:114: note:                 boost::thread::thread(boost::thread&)
main.cpp:397: warning: unused variable ‘new_thread’
```

Indeed, I'm newbie to boost.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `test` function overloaded:

```
//here
void test(const int * x, int d){
     for(int i=0; i<d ; i++)
         cout<< x[i] << endl;
 }

//somewhere
void test()
{
     std::cout <<"hahahahaha\n";
}
```

Now, when you specify `test` name

```
boost::thread *new_thread = new boost::thread(& test,x1,n);
```

Compiler cannot know, if you want to use one `test` function, or another.

- you should specify what overload you want to use:

  ```
  boost::thread *new_thread = new boost::thread((void(*)(const int*, int)) test,x1,n);
  ```
- or rename your `test` function